# What is the difference between '$%f' and '%f' in scanf?

Tags: c

um.. i have a question when i study standard input / output file system in C lang.

what's difference  '$%f' and '%f' ??

```
int main()
{
    int ctr;
    struct bookInfo books[3];

    for (ctr = 0; ctr < 3; ctr++)
    {
        printf(" what is book #%d? \n", (ctr + 1));
        gets(books[ctr].title);
        puts("who is author ? ");
        gets(books[ctr].author);
        puts("how much price this book?");
        scanf(" $%f", &books[ctr].price);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW, code will fail on 2nd loop.  Do not mix `gets()` with `scanf()`.

Answer (score 4):

`%f` is just normal float, and the `$` in the last `scanf`, is just a symbol: dollar symbol. There is actually no character such as `$%f`. Since the last `scanf` requires price of the book, you should put `$` before it (e.g. $20 equals 20 dollars).

Comment: But just acknowledge this- `scanf(" $%f", &books[ctr].price);` won't work. You may try this: `printf("how much price this book? $"); scanf("%f", &books[ctr].price);`

Answer (score 1):

`scanf(" $%f", &books[ctr].price);` scans from `stdin`

- 0 or more white-spaces
- a single `'$'`.  If not, scanning stops an`scanf()` returns 0 (or maybe `EOF`).
- If input text then matches a floating point number, it is saved  in `books[ctr].price`.